# How to read the block diagram for the 2nd order integrator feedback system?

Tags: signal

This is a prework for a lab, I haven't seen things in the picture before and have no idea on how to transfer this to an equation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wavy symbols are integrators, which means that:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = x_1$$
$$\frac{dx_1}{dt} = x_2$$

Then the "+" sign gives you (the triangles are "gains", which means multiply):

$$x_2 = x(t) - a_0 y(t) - a_1 x_1$$

If you combine all this together, you get your differential equation(s).